# Web Application and Site Collection

Tags: sharepoint-server, site-collection, web-application, sharepoint-on-prem

Recently, I was asked like why do we have a web application? What's the use of it? After listening to my answer I was questioned on the same as why can't we do the same for a site collection directly? Instead of creating a web application we can create a site collection itself with the same settings and all. At last, I convinced the questioner that there would be performance and security issues.

But I want to know the exact reason why it can't be. I would be grateful if anyone can help me get a better answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's imagine there is no web application to create the site collection, and you will create the site collection directly without creating a web application,

> In this case, Every site collection will require an **Application Pool** to be created !!

**So what's the issue, What's this mean?**

This means

- You will be restricted to create `maximum 10 site collection per the web server` based on its **hardware capabilities**.
- A single highly active application pool can utilize 10 GB or more, so More application pools will lead to a **Performance** Issue.

---

**Now, What do you think?**

> Do you need to create `250000 site collection per one web application` with the current SharePoint Structure and architecture?

[image]

> Or you need to be limited to the memory allocation of your web server
>   that allows to you to create 10 site collection based on hardware
>   capabilities at the same time you will face a Performance issue!!

---

**See also**

- [Compare SharePoint 2016 Application Pool limits with other SharePoint versions.](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/07/10/compare-sharepoint-2016-application-pool-limits-with-sharepoint-2013/)
- [Compare SharePoint 2016 Site Collection limits with other SharePoint versions](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/06/15/comparing-a-site-collection-limits-in-sharepoint-2016-with-sharepoint-201320102007/)